# Cordova background modes issues on Android/iOS

Tags: android, ios, cordova, windows-phone-8

I've ran into a problem with apache cordova background modes. I need to make an application where my battery level is checked from time to time in the background (if the app is in background), and if it is below some level, then the app should notify you about it. Eventually I've managed to run it on android, with katzer's plugin, it does work indeed, but after a while it shuts down completely and on iOS it does not even work. I've tried other plugins but nothing was helpful. Can you please help me find the problem with this? Also it must work on wp8/8.1 that's why katzer's plugin suited me best. (Not to misunderstand me, it is an outstanding plugin, in fact the only that works).

Here is the code [on Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/pVe3XVit)

Also I'm linking the plugin which I'm using [at the moment](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode)

Thanks in advance